# localDb not shows the insertion of rows in table in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, windows-console

In console application, rows are inserted in table successfully via entity Framework 6.1.3 in visual studio 2015, but when I check the entries in table manually, table didn't show any new row. 
But when I try my same code in MVC 4.5, then table shows the new rows entered via web browser successfully.

//Class mirror of database table

```
public partial class Table
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Table() { }
        public Table(String Name) {
            this.Name = Name;
        }


    }
```

//DB context class

```
public partial class Database1Entities : DbContext
    {
        public Database1Entities()
            : base("name=Database1Entities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Table> Tables { get; set; }
    }
```

//Insertion of rows in database

```
Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();
            db.Tables.Add(new Table("Ahsan"));
            db.Tables.Add(new Table("Ali"));
            db.Tables.Add(new Table("Butt"));
            db.Tables.Add(new Table("Arslan"));
            db.Tables.Add(new Table("Umer"));
            int x = db.SaveChanges();

            foreach (Table t in db.Tables)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.Name.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct database file opened when doing the manual check? One time I was confused, because I got several different version of a local db (mdf file) on my file system.

Comment: yeah, I'm sure. if I didn't open the correct file, otherwise running code must display the last new entries.